# How to convert pivot a list to a data frame

Tags: python

I have a list like this:

```
CODE    CONTENT
P   ABC
T   8/1/2008 0:00
Q   AAA
Q   BBB
P   XYZ
T   8/1/2008 0:00
Q   XXX
L   ASF
```

I need to convert the "list" to a table like using Python

```
P   T               Q        L
ABC 8/1/2008 0:00   AAABBB  
XYZ 8/1/2008 0:00   XXX      ASF
```

Which means, each time it encounter a P, it shall start a new line.

I am really new on this, appreciate any help!

Comment: What exactly signifies a new row in your table? Is it each occurrence of `P`? What would happen if you had `P ABC T   8/1/2008 0:00 T   8/1/2008 0:00 P XYZ`. Take some time to really think about what you want to do step by step, after you've done that the rest is basically just syntax.

Comment: yes, each p shall start a new line. If Q or L is absence,just leave blank.